# php exec() return wrong data

Tags: php, console

When I execute php script with `exec('vnstat -tr', $results);`
Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Sampling eth0 (5 seconds average)...                                    0 packets sampled in 5 seconds 
    [1] => Traffic average for eth0
    [2] =>
    [3] => rx 0.00 kbit/s 0 packets/s
    [4] => tx
0.00 kbit/s 0 packets/s
    [5] => )
```

When I execute vnstat -tr in console. 
Output look like this:

```
root@s2:~# vnstat -tr 313727 packets sampled in 5 seconds Traffic average for eth0

      rx        10,42 Mbit/s         20092 packets/s
      tx       488,22 Mbit/s         42653 packets/s
```

Someone Could tell my why PHP returned wrong data?

Comment: vnstat is outputting terminal control characters (e.g backspace) so it can update output on the same line of the terminal. you get "different" text in php because it doesn't obey those terminal control chars - it gives you the RAW output, including those control chars.

Comment: Could You tell me How I should fix this?

Comment: no idea. see if vnstat has an option to disable "terminalized" output like that, and only outputs the final results.